# Want to get all elements from the table

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

i have a website
login: cyclefreight1@usa.com
pas: 12345678, log in and go to the drivers section(left menu bar firs item > drivers)
 I want to make some additional function to this web with tampermonkey, i try to get all elements from the table, i do it with selector like this

```
var rows = document.querySelectorAll("#app table.table-component tr");
```

but all i have is undefined ^( , please give me some tips how can i do it, thank you

Answer (score 1):

The table is inside an `iframe` on another domain, so it's tricky to access. Include the userscript on that *other* domain, and give it a `setTimeout` to give the table time to populate:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         drivers
// @match        https://eldclient.trackingmap.eu/drivers*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

setTimeout(() => {
  const rows = document.querySelectorAll("#app table.table-component tr");
  console.log(rows);
}, 2000);
```