# get access to table in the iframe

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

i have a website , login: cyclefreight1@usa.com pas: 12345678, log in and go to the drivers section(left menu bar firs item > drivers) I want to make some additional function to this web with tampermonkey. All information about drivers consist in the table, and information about current driver is available when you click to "Go to the current log" button [image]

i try to add some new functions to the current drivers section
[image]
all this stuff are in the iframe , so i try to do an event listener to the button like this

```
// @name         drivers
// @match        https://eldclient.trackingmap.eu/drivers*
// @grant        none
// @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

setTimeout(() => {

    var el = document.getElementsByClassName("fa fa-file-text");
    console.log(el);
    el[1].addEventListener("click",console.log("yeah")) ;

}, 5000);
```

but it didn`t work , after click i want to get all the elements from table in the current log section.
In the drivers section it works for me

```
 **// @name         drivers
    // @match        https://eldclient.trackingmap.eu/drivers*
    // @grant        none
    // @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js
    // ==/UserScript==

    setTimeout(() => {
      const rows = document.querySelectorAll("#app table.table-component tr");
      console.log(rows);

    }, 5000);**
```

do you have any idea or tips , than you ^)

Comment: It is a CORs problem.

Comment: What 'didn't work'? When you added the handler to the button? When you clicked the button nothing happened? Is the time you are waiting to set the button handler enough time? Can you grab the iframe frame first? Set a debugger in the setTimeout routine and see what el is.

Comment: no seriously, the OP cannot access the iframe since it is cross origin and protected by the Same Origin Policy.

Comment: Yup, the top domain is gps.trackingmap.eu and the iframe domain is eldclient.trackingmap.eu. When domains differ, the iframe is essentially read-only and cannot be internally manipulated, for security reasons.

Comment: @RandyCasburn, this is not a CORS issue.  The script is nominally set to run on the correct iFrame.

Comment: @BrockAdams - you clearly have not run the sample app provided by the OP. Otherwise, with a little fiddling in the dev tools, that it is in fact, a CORs issue.

Comment: @Randy, I ran the correct script (not app) [provided by a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50327389/331508).  The OP's code has a great many problems, but CORS ain't one.  You clearly do not understand how Tampermonkey works with iframes.

Comment: @BrockAdams - interestingly enough, the CORs error that used to be in the console of that application _is no longer there_! But hey, whatevs.

Comment: So, i can`t do this, right ?

Comment: the problem is , i can`f figure out how to get access to the data of drivers in the table, i need some ideas about how can i do this